# Excel 2010 VBA - I am trying to record a macro that will shift two pivot table "items"

Tags: excel, vba

...from Report Filter to Legend Fields and viceversa, and I get an error...
This is the code it creates when recording:

```
Sub ByPlant()
'
' ByPlant Macro
'

'
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sociedad")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 2
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Proveedor")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
End Sub
```

And when I try to run it, it gives me this:

> run time error 1004 unable to get the pivottables property of the worksheet class

It highlights this line:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sociedad")
```

Can you guys help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it will throw that error if you have the wrong Pivot Table name.  Try qualifying the Worksheet.  Like `Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sociedad")`

Comment: @deusxmach1na That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much! EDIT: how can I mark your answer as helpfull? I am new...

Comment: @deusxmach1na, put your comment as an answer, so it can be marked as such

Answer (score 1):

That runtime error is thrown when the name of the pivot table is incorrect.  Try fixing it by qualifying the Worksheet like this.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sociedad")
```